# Result of SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate( fn:transform() ) doet not return root document node

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt, saxon-js

For a NodeJs tool I have to perform a simple transformation of XML using XSLT.

I want to use SaxonJs, but I do not want to get in the whole xslt3/sef thing (the xslt changes and the tool needs to run on computers without xslt3 installed).

There is an alternative and that is using the `fn:transform` function in an XPath expression.

While it seems to work exactly as I want, I can not perform any XPath *on the result* when I use certain expressions, because according to SaxonJs, the root node is not a document node.

So this works: `/*[1]/*[1]`

But this does not: `//*[@someAttr]/name`

Because then I get this error:

```
Exception has occurred: XError: Root node for '/' must be a document node
```

I do not get an error when I use the second XPath expression on my source document.

Also, when I serialize both the source and result, and diff them, they are identical in every way(!) (Except for a small change in attributes values, but that is what the XSLT is supposed to do)

This is my code:

```
const applyXsltToXml = function (xmlData, transformXslt) {

  const filteredXML = SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate(
    `fn:transform(map { ` +
      `'source-node': fn:parse-xml($xml), ` +
      `'stylesheet-node': fn:parse-xml($xslt), ` +
      `'delivery-format': 'raw' ` +
    `})?output`,
    null,
    { 'params': { 'xml': xmlData, 'xslt': transformXslt } }
  );

  if (_debug) {
    _write(`Xml transformed using Xslt; root node "${filteredXML?.localName}"`);
  }

  return filteredXML;
}
```

It seems to me that the problem is that the result XDM is somehow not correct. The differences I see when I compare the XDM of the source document and the result of the result XML:

- the `sourceDoc` has a `documentElement` property
- this `sourceDoc.documentElement` also has a `$d` property but in the XDM of  `transformedDoc` it is a direct child (`$d` contains the namespaces)
- `localName`/`nodeName`/`tagName` are also direct properties of `transformedDoc`, while in `sourceDoc` they can be seen in property `firstChild`

This is the XSLT I am using:

```
let xslt = `<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  
      <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
          <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
          </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>
  
      <!-- Filter out @cmyk -->
      <xsl:template match="@cmyk"/>
  
  </xsl:stylesheet>
  `;
```

It seems like there is just one small minor thing going wrong, but I can't see it. I have been looking at the arguments for `fn:transform` but could not find anything. Could it have something to do with `?output`?

Or do I need to convert the result into a document somehow?

---

**Update**

Thanks to @martin-honnen I now know it is the `.xslt` style-sheet that is the problem.

I tried a slightly different xslt v1 copy, but this also does not work.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
  
        <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
          <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
          </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
  
      <!-- Filter out -->
      <xsl:template match="@cmyk"/>
  
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

What could explain this?

Comment: If the answer I posted doesn't help then consider to edit your question and show minimal but complete samples of XML input and XSLT and JavaScript code that allows us to easily reproduce the error you get for your XPath evaluation attempts. It seems kind of odd that `/*[1]/*[1]` works but `//*[@someAttr]/name` doesn't as both use the `/` root document node, but it will be way easier to understand that if you post samples allowing us to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I will give you one example of using SaxonJS 2 (tested with 2.6 under Node.js) to run a stylesheet similar to yours (adapted to use XSLT 3 features) against an XML sample to return the transformation result as an XDM document on which subsequently an XPath evaluation is performed:

```
const SaxonJS = require("saxon-js");

const applyXsltToXml = function (xmlData, transformXslt) {

  const filteredXML = SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate(
    `transform(map {
      'source-node': fn:parse-xml($xml),
      'stylesheet-node': fn:parse-xml($xslt),
      'delivery-format': 'raw'
    })?output`,
    null,
    { 'params': { 'xml': xmlData, 'xslt': transformXslt } , resultForm : 'xdm'}
  )[0];

  return filteredXML;
}


const xmlExample1 = `<root>
  <foo>bar</foo>
  <bar cmyk="...">test</bar>
</root>`;

const xsltExample1 = `<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  
      <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
      <!-- Filter out @cmyk -->
      <xsl:template match="@cmyk"/>
  
  </xsl:stylesheet>`;
  
const resultExample1 = applyXsltToXml(xmlExample1, xsltExample1);

console.log(resultExample1);

const result2 = SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate(`count(//@cmyk)`, resultExample1);

console.log(result2);
```

The final XPath evalution returns 0.

As for your original attempts with using

```
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

there is a subtle difference between that template as the base template and the ones the XSLT 3 `xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"` defines as the template you use doesn't copy document nodes/root nodes but only element nodes/comment nodes/processing instruction nodes while the named `xsl:mode` declaration does an explicit shallow copy of the root node/document node. That explains why your `fn:transform` call returned an element node and for that indeed an attempt to use a path starting with `/` has to fail. I can't explain why you got `/*[1]/*[1]` to work, however.

Comment: I tried everything you suggested, including updating saxon-js to 2.6 (was 2.5), but only the stylesheet change did the trick... Still I don't understand why saxon-js would produce a different result (the XDM) for a xslt v1 copy compared to a xslt v3 copy...

Comment: @Sander_P, well, SaxonJS is an XSLT 3 processor, if you feed it `version="1.0"` code it processes it in backwards compatible code; that should, however, mainly affect things like `<xsl:value-of select="expression"/>` to output only the string value of the first item selected by `expression`, not of all items, like an XSLT 2 or XSLT 3 processor with normal processing mode/adequate version would do. I can't tell why/how it would affect a copy template as shown, but as before, if you run into an error, consider to post enough details (minimal but complete samples) to allow others to reproduce it.

Comment: If i am not mistaken, when you insert my xslt into your code, you will get the error when you try to do a XPath expression using '//'. Switching to Xslt 3 is not a big issue. Xslt 1 is probably outdated anyway. Thanks for helping!

Comment: @Sander_P, oh, indeed, that seems like an oddity or quirk of SaxonJS at least, I have raised it on the Saxonica SaxonJS forum to let them investigate whether they can explain it and/or want to fix it: https://saxonica.plan.io/boards/5/topics/9624